# Что значит стоимость вычисления при хэшировании пароля?

Tags: php, хеширование

В мане по php столкнулся с такой функцией хэширования `password_hash()`
в эту функцию передается три аргумента: пароль, алгоритм шифрования, дополнительные опции

Дополнительные опции здесь передаются как ассоциативный массив...в одном примере мана написано так:

```
$options = [
    'cost' => 11,
    'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
];
```

Понятно что salt - это соль и под значением понимается функция которая генерирует эту соль, но мне неясно одно, что такое cost, и какую роль оно играет при шифровании?

Comment: Вот кстати пример идеального вопроса для SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [достаточно развернутый ответ на английском языке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13912380/238336). А на Wiki есть [описание алгоритма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), где вы можете понять, в каком месте используется cost.

Если коротко, то cost влияет на количество операций при получении хэша, как степень числа 2. При cost = 11 у вас будет 2**11 повторений алгоритма для вычисления.

Answer (score 5):

Раньше различные хэширующие алгоритмы как MD5, SHA1 и SHA256 были спроектированы очень быстрыми и эффективными. При наличии современных технологий и оборудования, стало довольно просто выяснить результат этих алгоритмов методом "грубой силы" для определения оригинальных вводимых данных.

Появилось такое понятие как Cost - стоимость вычисления хеша.

Чем выше стоимость вычисления хэширующего алгоритма, тем больше времени требуется для взлома его вывода методом "грубой силы".

По сути при cost = 13. Стоимость вычислений равна 2^13 итераций [функции формирования ключа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0). Стандартный cost = 10 и вычисляется за миллисекунды, увеличение cost на 1, увеличивает время выполнения примерно в 2 раза.

Например cost = 13 выполняется за 0.2 ms, а вот cost = 16 уже будет выполнен за несколько секунд.